# Php file URL does displays homepage instead of php file

Tags: php, html

The proxy URL at px.multiscreensite.com works through the php file stored at px.multiscreensite.com/index.php, but when trying to investigate the code by viewing the php file it just displays exactly identical code to the homepage. Why can't I view the php file, is there some trick being used. In case you can't view the webpage because its blocked, it is a proxy after all, here is the webpage code:

```
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="title">PHProxy</h1>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="https://px.multiscreensite.com/">URL Form</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('cookie managment has not been implemented yet')">Manage Cookies</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form method="post" action="https://px.multiscreensite.com/index.php">
    <ul id="form">
      <li id="address_bar"><label>Web Address <input id="address_box" type="text" name="url" value="" onfocus="this.select()" /></label> <input id="go" type="submit" value="Go" /></li>
      <li class="option"><label><input type="checkbox" name="hl[remove_scripts]" />Remove client-side scripting (i.e JavaScript)</label></li>
<li class="option"><label><input type="checkbox" name="hl[strip_meta]" />Strip meta information tags from pages</label></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
  <!-- The least you could do is leave this link back as it is. This software is provided for free and I ask nothing in return except that you leave this link intact
   You're more likely to recieve support should you require some if I see a link back in your installation than if not -->
  <div id="footer"><a href="http://whitefyre.com/poxy/">PHProxy</a> 0.5b2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Client can't see php code coz it is processed at server side

Comment: What you observe is a general thing. There _never_ is a way for some client to access the server side script code. Unless there is an extrem sever miss configuration on the server side, of course. Such access would be a major security issue and not in the interest of anyone using a scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because PHP is a server-side language. All of the PHP code written is processed by the website's machines, and therefore the source code is never sent to your computer. This is an intended result and one of the fundamental aspects of a server-side language.